# Sum of Max functions using an array formula Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a formula that results in the following:

```
sum(max(a,b),max(c,d),....)
```

I tried using `=SUM(MAX(0,($D$1:$P$1)-$P$3)` as an *array formula*, but this results in excel taking the maximum of all the entries, instead I want the sum of all maximums.

Comment: Is this the maximum of - what? Each column? A single row?

Comment: it is calculating the excess of entries in a column over the value in cell P3.

Comment: Do you want to sum all the values were difference is greater than zero and ignore all the ones that are less than zero?

Comment: yes. just the sum of the positive differences

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum a range, say `A1:H1` if it's greater than a cell, say `H3`. But you don't want to sum the total, you want to sum the differences between the cells in the range that meet the criteria and the cell they are being compared to, right?

```
=SUMIF(A1:H1,">"&H3)-(COUNTIF(A1:H1,">"&H3)*H3)
```

It *doesn't* need to be entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shft</kbd> <kbd>entr</kbd> as [sumif is already an array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/275165). Adapt to your conditions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D1:P1-P3>0)*(D1:P1-P3))
```

The first set of parens returns a bunch of Trues and Falses. When multiplied, Trues are like 1's and Falses are like 0's. So when something is below zero, it gets multiplied by zero and becomes zero.